# add support for news/nntp URLs

Tags: feature-request, markdown, hyperlinks

I was trying to link to a gmane article in [that answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/614823), but none of the:

```
[message](news://news.gmane.io:119/4DC939FC.2040407@redhat.com)
[message](nntp://news.gmane.io/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/4151)
<a href="nntp://news.gmane.io/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/4151">message</a>
<a href="news://news.gmane.io:119/4DC939FC.2040407@redhat.com">message</a>
```

URLs seem to work.

That just gives:

> message
> message
> message
> message

That's [RFC5538 URLs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5538) that have been supported by `lynx` for instance for decades (`news://news.gmane.io/4DC939FC.2040407@redhat.com` URLs also still work in [SeaMonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SeaMonkey)).

A lot of the Unix history is documented on usenet (which predates the world wide web), and gmane which contains archives of a lot of Unix-related mailing lists (including the POSIX working group's whose earlier posts can only be found publicly there) is nowadays only available over NNTP.

Usenet is or at least was core to the Unix culture. Unix.SE is to some extent a bit of the continuation of `comp.unix.*` / `comp.os.linux.*`. I recognise a few names from there here.

It would be useful to allow those links at least on the unix.SE site.

Comment: How do these links open for you? I can't get my firefox to treat `news://` or `nntp://` as links, it goes straight to searching for them in a search engine.

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with CommonMark, but am aware of recent changes there: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/307535

Comment: @JeffSchaller I'm thinking it might be because the `news://` and `nntp://` aren't recognized as valid URLs (and they aren't, as far as I can tell). Maybe Stéphane has some sort of browser extension that can handle them? Or am I alone in not being able to get them to open? Stéphane, did these used to work in the past?

Comment: @terdon, they are standard. They're in [RFC1738](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738) (1994). Not many browsers still support them. `lynx` does as I said in the question, and you can always configure your firefox to spawn `lynx` in an xterm to handle them.

Comment: Ah, yes sorry. I had missed the part about lynx. Fair enough.